# Controlling over flow when calculating time

Tags: java, time, int, joptionpane, parseint

im looking for some  help solving a little issue. 
I know what needs to be done i just dont know how to write the code. 
so i am accuring time integers through Joptionpane boxes  and  then trying to work out the total time taken. I have the code to do this but the issue i have is if i enter 12:34:23  (hh/mm/ss) for the start time then 13:44:33 it will out put  totaltime as 01:-10:-10 rather than 00:49:50

Thanks in advance. I can send  my code if  needed, there is just a lot of  it and people will  lecture me about the layout of my  code and  not help  with the actual problem in hand.

these  are my int inputs. not start  time and  end time has 3 sepreate ints which is probably why im  having trouble

```
        String Starth = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Competitor Enter your Start time (hours)" );
                        int  Starthour=Integer.parseInt(Starth);          

        String Startm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Competitor Enter your Start time (mins)" );
                        int  Startmin=Integer.parseInt(Startm);

        String Starts = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Competitor Enter your Start time (secs)" );
                        int Startsec=Integer.parseInt(Starts);

        String  Endh = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Competitor Enter your End time (hours)" );
                        int  Endhour=Integer.parseInt(Endh);

        String Endm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Competitor Enter your End Time (mins)" );
                        int Endmin=Integer.parseInt(Endm);    

        String Ends = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Competitor Enter your End Time (secs)" );
                        int Endsec=Integer.parseInt(Ends);
```

and  this is  my current  code working  out the time taken

```
  int Timeh = (Endhour - Starthour);    
        int Timem = (Endmin - Startmin);
        int Times = (Endsec - Startsec);
```

at the end of the code i  use system.out.print(" " +Timeh+Timem+Times)

Ok so my problem is my code wont take a minute or hour off the total if the end time  in mins or seconds is less  than the start time mins or seconds, it will just print out a minus figure. 
im working it out currently  just  by taking the start time from the end time. 
eg
Start time:
12:45:45
Endtime:
14:30:30

curently  produces
Total time:
02:-15:-15

which isnt  a unit of hours/mins/seconds
Sorry if im  not being clear with my problem

Comment: Please create a sample program that demonstrates your problem. Show us a method that takes two strings (e.g. `12:34:23` and `13:44:33`) and produces `01:-10:-10`. We'll then help you fix it.

Comment: Why do you think the total time is 00:49:50?

Comment: Did you see my first comment? If you'd done exactly what I asked, this would be much easier for us to solve. Instead, you've lazily copied chunks of your code into your question. Take the time to write a (very simple) example method.

Comment: Your updated post does not explain why you think the difference is 00:49:50. The correct difference is 01:10:10.

Comment: Sorry  james, youre correct im  terrible with math

Answer (score 0):

u can use SimpleDateFormat and Date class. like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date d1 = format.parse("12:34:23");
        Date d2 = format.parse("13:44:33");
        Date d3 = new Date((long) d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());     

        System.out.println(format.format(d1));
        System.out.println(format.format(d2));
        System.out.println(format.format(d3));
    }
```